# Not using method in derived class

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism

Uni assignment requires that we build a pizza app in C# that derives `Sauce` from `Ingredient`. I have a `List<Ingredient>` that is storing objects of both types.

`Pizza.cs` calls the method `GetInstructions()` which is slightly different in the derived method. Unfortunately `Sauce.GetInstructions()` is never being called. As you can see, there's a debug line in there that should pop up a message box when the program is executing that routine but it's not popping up. Can anyone suggest why not?

`Pizza.cs` contains the following method:

```
public string BuildInstructionList()
    {   // iterate through list of selected toppings and build a single string for display in the GUI
    int count = 1; string instructions = "";
    foreach (var i in toppings)
        {
        instructions = instructions += string.Format("Step {0}: {1}", count, i.GetInstructions());
        count++;
        }
        return instructions;
    }
```

`Ingredient.cs` contains:

```
public virtual string GetInstructions()
    {
        string instructionLine;
        string qty = this.GetIngredientQuantity().ToString();
        string unit = this.GetIngredientUnit();
        string name = this.GetIngredientName();
        instructionLine = string.Format("Add {0} {1} of {2} to the pizza.\n", qty, unit, name);
        return instructionLine;
    }
```

`Sauce.cs` contains:

```
public new string GetInstructions()
    {
        PizzaGUI.Message("I am here!");
        string instructionLine;
        string qty = this.GetIngredientQuantity().ToString();
        string unit = this.GetIngredientUnit();
        string name = this.GetIngredientName();
        instructionLine = string.Format("Apply {0} {1} of {2} to the pizza.\n", qty, unit, name);
        return instructionLine;
    }
```

Comment: Check out the difference between method overriding and method hiding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `override` in place `new` in your Sauce.cs method.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx) The override modifier extends the base class method, and the new modifier hides it.

```
public override string GetInstructions()
    {
        PizzaGUI.Message("I am here!");
        string instructionLine;
        string qty = this.GetIngredientQuantity().ToString();
        string unit = this.GetIngredientUnit();
        string name = this.GetIngredientName();
        instructionLine = string.Format("Apply {0} {1} of {2} to the pizza.\n", qty, unit, name);
        return instructionLine;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed that and it's now using the Sauce version, but it's using it for all toppings, not just the sauces!

Comment: Clarification, after the first time I use it, it keeps using it. E.g. if I add mushrooms then it uses the `Ingredient` version, then I add a sauce, it uses the `Sauce` version, and any subsequent toppings (onions etc.) it keeps using the `Sauce` version.

Comment: uh... actually it is and isn't. Subsequent additions of toppings are using the correct string format line (which contains the word Add) but for some reason it's triggering the messagebox!

Comment: Ignore previous comments. I was being a newb and misreading my own debug lines. They're popping up because it's iterating through and rebuilding the list each time. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In Sauce.cs,

Change:

```
public new string GetInstructions()
```

To:

```
public override string GetInstructions()
```

The *new* keyword will basically ignore the base definition, and create a brand new method that is also called `GetInstructions`, hiding the virtual method you defined in the base class.  You've broken polymorphism when you do this.

I would also suggest making the `Ingredient` class abstract, and not define an implementation for `GetInstructions`.